# How can I allocate this element?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to get the text from an element. How can I do that? I am working with C# and Selenium.

I don't know how to copy-paste the HTML here(is it even possible?), so I am providing a screenshot of it, here it is:

[image]

This "1.27"is the text variable and this is what I am trying to get. How can I do that?

I tried with - //p[@class='sc-1xf18x6-0 sc-1aqfqq9-0 iUhqVy ghtrzb']
but it allocates 2 elements - please see screenshots:

Screenshot 1 - the one I need (even if I allocate it correctly, after that I still need to get just the second text - 1.27 and not the 1st text - Floor Price:)
[image]

Screenshot 2 -
[image]

I just remembered that I can make a list of those 2 allocated elements probably but if there is a easier way I will be happy to hear it.

Please let me know if I need to provide other info in order for you guys to help me out, I am new here.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as text. You can copy the HTML directly from the HTML inspector.

Answer (score 1):

The question has nothing to do with selenium itself. You need just a way to locate the desired element, so one way is to use `xpath`:

```
//p[contains(normalize-space(text()), 'Floor price')]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thank you for the answer - it does work. I do have another question, I need to allocate another element, please see the link, I will really appreciate it if you could help me with that too.

https://gyazo.com/8418e5c7b5c3a5a988bdd9e26c57a9aa

I need to allocate this variable text "1.0807".
How do I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: if span class price raw symbol is unique then use this as reference or otherwise use text() again. So let's say that class is not unique: `//span[text() = 'WETH']/..`
The idea here is to locate an element that is easy to be located and then to go to parent div

Comment: //span[text() = 'WETH']/..  - this does work. I don't know why I didn't think of this myself, it seems so easy now when explained. Thank you for your help!